# Ping computername - result format

Tags: windows-7, ping

I am trying PING command on my Windows 7 PC after many months.  While doing this, I notice the following result:

Ping using computer name:

```
D:\>ping amdwin764

Pinging AMDWIN764 [fe80::ac53:546f:a730:8bd6%11] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::ac53:546f:a730:8bd6%11: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::ac53:546f:a730:8bd6%11: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::ac53:546f:a730:8bd6%11: time=1ms
Reply from fe80::ac53:546f:a730:8bd6%11: time=1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::ac53:546f:a730:8bd6%11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

Ping using IP address:

```
D:\>ping 192.168.1.2

Pinging 192.168.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time=75ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.1.2: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 75ms, Average = 19ms
```

Why am I not getting the Ping results with Numeric IP address in my first example?

Thanks,
Kamlesh

Answer (score 12):

It is pinging using IPv6. You can force the ping command to use the IPv4 command using the -4 option.

c:\ > ping -4 AMDWIN764

Comment: Got it. It works with -4 option.  But, I am wondering how did this change happened!  I didn't change any settings on my PC.  

Also one more observation, when I do "ping www.google.com", it pings with default number format IP address.

Comment: @kamleshrao: Windows 7 now has IPv6 support enabled by default. Older releases didn't.

Comment: @kamleshrao: As for the second observation - Google doesn't support IPv6 yet. (Not on their primary domain, at least: try `ipv6.google.com` and compare.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are seeing with the host name is the IPv6 IP address. Without knowing for sure I'd guess that when you ping an IP address you ping that IP address, and when you ping a host name if it tries to resolve it as an IPv6 IP address and if it succeeds that IP is what you see.